# SQL works in SSMS but not on SSRS Report?

Tags: sql, t-sql, reporting-services, ssrs-2008

I have the following piece of SQL:

```
select 
    l.lease_id ,
    l.tenant_trading_name ,
    p.building_name ,
    l.negotiation_type ,
    l.net_area ,
    l.lease_source ,
    l.deal_approved_date ,
    l.building_id ,
    p.building_id as building_id_2
from 
    lease_deal.lease l
    inner join property.property p
        on p.building_id = l.building_id
where 
    l.deal_approved_date >= @dateFrom
    and l.deal_approved_date  <= @dateTo
    and l.lease_status = @leaseStatus
```

This works perfectly fine in SSMS (providing I declare the variables) however when I've added it as a dataset on a report (called dsDetail) I'm receiving the following error when the report tries to run:

> An error occurred during client rendering. An error has occurred
>   during report processing. Query execution failed for dataset
>   'dsDetail'. Must declare the scalar variable "@building_id". Incorrect
>   syntax near the keyword 'and'.

I don't understand what the error is indicating and after Googling the issue for the past half hour feel no closer to a resolution. Please help!

Comment: Also worth noting that the last two columns weren't originally a part of my query, I simply added them to see if maybe not having them was hurting the join in ssrs.

Comment: I dont see @building_id in your query.  Where is SSRS getting that?

Comment: @Alex It's not, which is why I don't understand. I've inherited this report so it's potentially a variable from dsDetail in a previous version (I'll check version control shortly). Is there some way SSRS can be referencing an older version of this dataset somehow?

Comment: @Alex Resolved: Unsure what caused this but appears to be a strange caching issue. Completely removed the report from SSRS and re-uploaded it. Thank-you, greatly appreciate your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Resolved: Unsure what caused this but appears to be a strange caching issue. Completely removed the report from SSRS and re-uploaded it.

Comment: I've found that sometimes variables aren't completely removed from reports when they are deleted. Another option to resolve is to right-click the report in solution explorer -> view code. Then search for the parameter name and remove it from the XML.

Answer (score 1):

The queries you use differ. Since here is no such a variable - check the query used in SSRS.

Comment: I found that there was in a previous version, this led me to delete and re-upload the report and everything has worked from here. Thank-you very much for your assistance all the same!